# Azure Authentication for Deployment - Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-deployment

For deployment to Azure we need to authenticate, and we have two methods to achieve this.

**1. Publish Setting File**

Download the publish setting and use the Subscription Name to Set the subscription before deployment

**2. Managed Certificate**

Create and upload the .cer file to the management Portal.

Use the associated .pfx to be installed in the client machine during deployment, and authenticate with the thumbprints.

Can someone tell me which one is better in terms of security, manageability and ease of usage?

Comment: Not sure why this question is voted down! Could you please let me know the reason ?

Comment: no certs: do it with AAD login by means of powershell, .NEt, Rest API or MAML ... try to avoid certificates